# Эквивалент Blank App (XAML) из Visual Studio 2012 в Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Решил начать изучать C# по книге "Изучаем C#" 3-е издание Э. Стиллмен, Д. Грин. И сразу же начались проблемы, т.к. в книге используется **Visual Studio 2012**.
Там написано создать новый проект **Visual C# > Windows Store > Blank App (XAML)**. В **Visual Studio 2015 Community** этого нет. Подскажите пожалуйста какой проект в данном случае создавать.

Comment: а что есть?????

Comment: зато есть Blank App (Windows 8.1)

Comment: я склоняюсь к одному из этих вариантов: Пустое приложение (Windows 8.1), Пустое приложение (универсальные приложения Windows 8.1), Приложение WPF

Comment: в вашей книге ключевое это `Windows Store`, а значит для того, чтобы увидеть знакомый по книге проект вам нужно Blank App (Windows 8.1) . Но, лучше уж найдите книгу посвежее.

Comment: спасибо, к сожалению свежей версии этой книги нету в природе, а хотелось бы по этой заниматься

Comment: @FoggyFinder, почему?